# What language is on the "God's Message" Cube?

Tags: crystal-triangle

In **Crystal Triangle**, there's an ancient relic in the shape of a cube that's got writing all over it and is referred to as "God's Message".

[image]

At first glance, it looks like it's based on Aramaic:

[image]

But then when we get a really good look at it, it doesn't look Aramaic at all:

[image]

Is this based on any kind of real world language/alphabet (similar to how the writing at the end of the Evangelion opening sequence is based on [Angelic Script](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/angelic.htm))? Or is it completely made up?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this show, nor have I researched the question, so take this answer with a grain of salt.

At first glance, the inscriptions look like Chinese characters (*hanzi*) or Japanese characters (*kanji*) that have been modified a bit to look 'archaic' or chiseled into stone. I've taken the second picture and added in the Chinese characters (in red) that I think some of the etchings are similar to.

[image]